# Query nested JSON array for specific keys only in Nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, underscore.js, flat

Let's say I have an array of JSON objects as shown below:

```
[{  "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
    "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    },
    "hobbies":['cricket', 'football']},{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Graham",
    "username": "David",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "San Jose",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "39.3159",
        "lng": "121.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": ["1-770-736-8031 x56442", "4087917884", "4089088939"],
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "dept":[{"name":"divya", "address":"abc"},{"name":"divya1", "address":"abc1"}],
    "hobbies":['baseball']}]
```

Now I wanted to get the data based on specific keys and keys can be nested keys also. Let's take an example that I wanted to get the data of this keys only: 'name', 'username', 'city', 'lat', 'lng'. so the output will be shown as below:

```
[{
   name:'Leanne Graham', 
   username:'Bret', 
   address.city:'Gwenborough', 
   address.geo.lat:"-37.3159",
   address.geo.lng: "81.1496"
 },
 {
   name:'Graham', 
   username:'David', 
   address.city:'San Jose', 
   address.geo.lat:"39.3159",
   address.geo.lng: "121.1496
}]
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this on NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to perform complex data queries is to rely on a data-storage engine that supports a rich enough query language to meet your needs. [Mongo](http://www.mongodb.com), [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com) and [Elasticsearch](http://www.elastic.com) are examples of storage engines with fully featured query languages built in.

Another approach would be to use a functional library like [Lodash](http://www.lodash.com) or [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) to construct your data extraction pipelines.

Using Lodash to extract from the data example you provide:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

// paths to extract from matching records

const field_paths = [
  'name', 
  'username', 
  'address.city', 
  'address.geo.lat', 
  'address.geo.lng']

// extract value at field_paths and add to result

const extract_fields = (rec) => {
  let res = {}
  field_paths.forEach((path) => {
    res[path] = _.get(rec, path)
  })
  return res
}

// query for all records where 
// name is like "*Graham*" irrespective of letter case.
// 
// and extract required fields from matching records

const results = _(data)
  .filter((rec) => _.get(rec, 'name').match(/\bgraham\b/i))
  .map(extract_fields)
  .value()

console.log(results)
```

will print:

```
[ { name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    'address.city': 'Gwenborough',
    'address.geo.lat': '-37.3159',
    'address.geo.lng': '81.1496' },
  { name: 'Graham',
    username: 'David',
    'address.city': 'San Jose',
    'address.geo.lat': '39.3159',
    'address.geo.lng': '121.1496' } ]
```

Comment: And just for the record, I'm aware that this operation could be represented by a single lodash chain but wanted my answer to be readable to those unfamiliar with functional programming.

Comment: I'm curious why someone would downvote my answer considering it fully addresses the OP's concerns.

Answer (score -1):

If you are open to install a dependency you can look for `lodash.get`;

```
npm i --save lodash.get
```

This will allow you to:

```
const _get = require('lodash.get');

_get(obj, 'address.city'); // "San Jose"
```

With this utility it will be much easier for you to query an object for specific key/values and compose custom objects based on your requirements.

Otherwise you can create your own safe accessor function:

```
function getKey(key, obj) {
  return key.split('.').reduce(function(a,b){
    return a && a[b];
  }, obj);
}

getKey('address.city'', obj); // "San Jose"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. I know about lodash but I want to get the data of that particular keys only. You can thnik about remove the other keys and values.